# Oracle 11.2.0.1.0_GROUP BY without aggregate functions doesn't raise error?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Today I face a very weird problem that I have searched with no luck. In one of our procedure I meet this query:

```
select count(*) into b_count 
from (
    select col1, col2, col3 
    from table_name 
    where col_id = b_id and col3 = b_col3 
    group by col1, col2);
```

Let's not talk about this poor query that we could rewrite without using subquery.

The problem here is in our development database, oracle didn't raise `ORA-00979 not a GROUP BY expression` and we could run the procedure normally (no control, no if else,....). And in our real database it did raise error.

Did someone ever meet this before? Could someone explain this to me?

As trying to reproduce the problem, I write this query and it run fine in our developement db (result count(*) = 2 not 3), and yes error 00979 in our real db:

```
WITH table_name AS 
(
    SELECT 1 col1, 2 col2, 3 col3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 3, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 7, 8 FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, col3
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY col1
);
```

P/S: our dev db:

> Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Our real db:

> Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Did 11.2.0.1.0's query optimizer be "smarter" that is omitted the SELECT statement in subquery and only use the SELECT COUNT(*) in main query? Or it's some setup in Oracle that I don't know?

And this is query plan in the dev db, it seems not different from a running query like `SELECT SUM(col3) FROM (SELECT col1, MAX(col3) col3 FROM table_name GROUP BY col1)`
[image]

Comment: I suspect that your hunch is right . . . the query optimizer is being smart by ignoring the contents of the `select` because they are not needed for the actual query.

Comment: What does the Explain Plan show for the query in the development db? That should give you some clues to what the optimizer did.

Comment: This query fails in 12.1.0.2. I suspect that this was a bug in 11.2.0.1 that has  subsequently been fixed :)